# Bootstrap search input on menu breaks the style on smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a search menu on navbar using bootstrap it's working ok when used in larger screen but not working in smaller sreeen size, here is the menu example, I also would like make a better Stylish menu if you guys can help please also **help me to make a better Stylish menu.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- form here -->
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
 
       <input type="text" class="form-control search-form" placeholder="search">
         <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary search-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button> </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This style I wish in the search menu see the [example](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/stylish-search-box) but I wish rounded corners

Comment: This looks like only a search form and not a complete navbar. [See the examples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default). Creating "a better Stylish menu" is subjective so you need to clarify what you expect and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this structure and link the button to the input

Basically you need to wrap the input and button in div with class **input-group-btn** which makes them aligned and stuck together even in small screen

```css
#custom-search-input {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

#custom-search-input .search-query {
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-right: 4px \9;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px \9;
  /* IE7-8 doesn't have border-radius, so don't indent the padding */
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#custom-search-input button {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  /** belows styles are working good */
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
  left: -28px;
  /* IE7-8 doesn't have border-radius, so don't indent the padding */
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #D9230F;
}

.search-query:focus+button {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- form here -->

  <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div id="custom-search-input">
      <div class="input-group col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="  search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
           <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is how you use it in a navbar menu :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: The class input-group-btn is the one making the input and the button stuck together even in small screen .. you can also use it to group buttons together

Comment: Nice, could you help me to make a better style for this search form in navbar menu?

Comment: You didn't post your navbar menu... have you made it yet?

Comment: @Developer see my edit.. you can find out how to put it in a navbar menu

Comment: I would like a menu like it , also the possibility to make it rounded corners http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/stylish-search-box

Comment: @Developer if you copy the code as it is, you will get the result... anyway you can see my answer and cheers :)

Comment: yeah but how to make it rounded corners?

Comment: @Developer Just increase the value of border-radius of the input ... see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group add-on">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your example